# Rmarkdown add custom div to table of contents

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I am working on an Rmarkdown document and I have created a title that has multiple colours using `css`:

```
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    code_folding: "hide"
    theme: readable    
---
<div>
  <span style="font-size:2em;font-weight: bold">Part 1 </span> 
  <span style="color:green;font-size:2em;font-weight: bold">Part 2</span> 
</div>
```

How can I add the sentence to the table of contents?

I tried changing the properties of the `<div>` to class="section level1 unnumbered" but this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `rmarkdown` just looks for things with the standard header markers like `#` or the resulting `<h1>` to determine what to put in the TOC.  But you can include HTML markup within those, e.g.

```
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    code_folding: "hide"
    theme: readable    
---

# Part 1 <span style="color:green">Part 2</span>
```

which displays as

[image]

Comment: Yes that is the answer. I simply changed the <div> element to <h1> element in my snippet above and it all worked... Thank you!

Comment: I thought it was looking at the Markdown rather than the HTML; I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well I guess it reads the # part and interprets it as simply <h1> and then adds the inner parts to it...